# Why is my website scrape missing the intended table using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find, web-inspector

I am trying to use this code to scrape information from Ballotpedia (https://ballotpedia.org/Governor_(state_executive_office)), specifically names of executives. The code I have here is only giving me the following output:

```
,Governor_(state_executive_office),Lieutenant_Governor_(state_executive_office),Secretary_of_State_(state_executive_office),Attorney_General_(state_executive_office)
```

I am trying to get the names as well. Here is my current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Governor_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Lieutenant_Governor_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Secretary_of_State_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Attorney_General_(state_executive_office)']

temp_dict = {}

for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in 
soup.select("table.bptable.gray.sortable.tablesorter 
tablesorter-default tablesorter17e7f0d6cf4b4 jquery- 
tablesorter")]
```

The very last line is the one in which I believe the problem exists. I have tried removing and adding code to the section "table.bptable.gray.sortable.tablesorter tablesorter-default tablesorter17e7f0d6cf4b4 jquery-tablesorter" but keep getting the same result. I copied it straight from the site no I'm not sure what I'm missing. If not this, is there something wrong with the rest of the code in that line? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to reach the table via selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Governor_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Lieutenant_Governor_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Secretary_of_State_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Attorney_General_(state_executive_office)']

temp_dict = {}

for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')    
    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in soup.select('#officeholder-table')]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler way to do it. Taking one of your urls at random, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("https://ballotpedia.org/Governor_(state_executive_office)")
tables[4]
```

Output:

```
    Office  Name    Party   Date assumed office
0   Governor of Georgia     Brian Kemp  Republican  January 14, 2019
1   Governor of Tennessee   Bill Lee    Republican  January 15, 2019
2   Governor of Missouri    Mike Parson     Republican  June 1, 2018
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use following css selector to find the table first and then use `pandas` to read_html()
and load into data frame.
This will give you all data in a single dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

listurl = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Governor_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Lieutenant_Governor_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Secretary_of_State_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Attorney_General_(state_executive_office)']

df1=pd.DataFrame()
for l in listurl:
    res=requests.get(l)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
    table=soup.select("table#officeholder-table")[-1]
    df= pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df1=df1.append(df,ignore_index=True)

print(df1)
```

---

If you want to fetch individual dataframe then try this.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

listurl = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Governor_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Lieutenant_Governor_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Secretary_of_State_(state_executive_office)', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Attorney_General_(state_executive_office)']

for l in listurl:
    res=requests.get(l)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
    table=soup.select("table#officeholder-table")[-1]
    df= pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    print(df)
```

Comment: To convert in dictionary just do this `print(df1.to_dict())` for fisrt one.second one`print(df.to_dict())`